# SQL Server : convert string with format dddd mm/dd/yy to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, format, sql-server-2012

How can I convert string with format `dddd mm/dd/yy` to date in SQL Server?

e.g. `Wednesday 1/9/13`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you eliminate the day of the week, you can just convert the rest of the value.

The following works:

```
select cast(right(col, len(col) - charindex(' ', col)) as date)
from (select 'Wednesday 1/9/13' as col) t;
```

EDIT:

Aaron makes a good point.  You can ensure the conversion by using `convert` with a style of "1":

```
select convert(date, right(col, len(col) - charindex(' ', col)) , 1)
from (select 'Wednesday 1/9/13' as col) t;
```

(101 doesn't work because it expects a 4-digit year.)

Comment: I would use convert with 101 to be sure that isn't interpreted as September 1st.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The actual style is "1", because the year is two digits.  But thanks, I made the suggestion to use `convert()`.

Comment: Well to be honest I'm not sure the OP is convinced about input or output - the title says `yyyy`, the body says `yyy` and the example says `yy`.